# Oracle coherence caching, specifying expiry timeout while adding the object into cache

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

I am using oracle coherence caching.

For configuring expiry, there is a parameter called 'expiry-delay' to configure the expiry in xml file.

I would like to know if it is possible to pass the expiry duration while adding the object into the cache.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set TTL value when you put new item to the cache

```
Object put(Object oKey,
       Object oValue,
       long cMillis)
```

[CacheMap JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/330/com/tangosol/net/cache/CacheMap.html#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke the method `put(Object oKey, Object oValue, long cMillis)` on the `NamedCache` you hold. When calling this method, your entry will expire exactly after `cMillis` it is committed to the cache (and committed to the DB if you have persistency). By this way, Coherence will ignore the default value set in the scheme definition.
If you wanna use anyway the default value, you can use `CacheMap.EXPIRY_DEFAULT` as value.

Comment: How can you specify in the default value in the schema definition. We tried to add <expiry-delay> tag in the schema but it didn't work. Is there any other option?

Comment: Please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/cache_config.htm for more information about the expiry-delay. It doesn't work as probably you expects since the concept is a bit different. I strongly recommend to read the definition in the link.

Comment: Since Coherence 12.2.1: _Cache entries are proactively evicted from a backing map after the cache expiry time is reached and no longer require a cache operation to initiate the eviction._ (links: [12.2.1 Release Notes](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/coherence/release-notes/technotes.htm#:~:text=proactively%20evicted), [12.1.3 DevGuide](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/cache_config.htm#sthref48) vs. [12.2.1.4 DevGuide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/coherence/12.2.1.4/develop-applications/configuring-caches.html#COHDG5352))